# Could anyone help me find the error in this simple C# program?

Tags: c#, oop, console

I was just wondering if someone could help me out, I am trying to compile this c# program and csc.exe keeps returning the error

> Exercise_.cs<11,25>: error CS1002: ; expected

Though I cannot find a missing semicolon...any help would really be appreciated.

```
using System;

namespace _8546574 {


    class exercise_8 {

        static void Main(string[] args){

            bool running = true;
            While(running = true){
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number between 1 and 3");
            Console.Clear();
            int input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            switch(input){

            case 1: 
                Console.WriteLine("You entered 1");
                running = false;
                Console.ReadLine(); 
                break;

            case 2: 
                Console.WriteLine ("You entered 2 :)"); 
                running = false;
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;

            case 3: 
                Console.WriteLine("You entered 3");
                running = false;
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;

            default:
                Console.WriteLine("failed");
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: `While(running = true){` should be `==`....and `while`, too (edited to make myself look smart. I totally missed the "W".... )

Comment: and should be `while` not `While`. C# thinks `While(running = true)` is a method call and is missing the final `;`. Also indenting correctly would make it easier to find matching braces. Btw.: simply  `while(running)` does the same.

Comment: `while` and not `While`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I just noticed that you have While and it should be while.

```
while(running == true)
```

or

```
while(running)
```

Answer (score 1):

replace your line `While(running = true){` with `while(running){` that should work

`while` must be lowercase and the check can `(running)` or `(running == true)`

Comment: Thanks for your help :) though now it returns "Exercise_8.cs<11,18>: error CS1002: ; expected"......

Comment: @Mr.L: Your compiler is telling you exactly where the error occurs (line 11, column 18). Should be easy to find.

Comment: yep, a `}` missing at the end

Answer (score 0):

From copying your code exactly as written, you need to make while lower case, and add an extra } to the end of the code. everything else compiles fine